# Поиск совпадения по последним символам и вывод результата

Tags: php, mysql

Есть значение $_SESSION['USERNAME']  Как создать запрос в базу чтобы он сравнил $_SESSION['USERNAME'] с последними 6 цифрами из поля USERNAME из table1 и если есть совпадение вывел поле USERNAME на страницу. Записей в базе не так много. Если нет совпадения то ничего бы не делал. $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = 9 значное число.

Comment: $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = 9 значное число сравнить с последними 6 цифрами из поля USERNAME. Как их нужно сравнить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы извлечь последние 6 символов строки, можно воспользоваться функцией SUBSTR(), которая имеется как в PHP, так и в MySQL. Достаточно в качестве второго параметра передать значение -6 и она извлечет последние 6 символов строки. Далее достаточно выполнить обычный SELECT-запрос с условием WHERE. При использовании расширения PDO, скрипт выполняющий эту задачу может выглядеть следующим образом

```
<?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
        'root',
        '',
        [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM table1
              WHERE SUBSTR(USERNAME, -6) = :username";
    $cat = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $cat->execute(['username' => substr($_SESSION['USERNAME'], -6) ]);
    $result = $cat->fetch();
    echo $result['username'];
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Невозможно установить соединение с базой данных";
}
```

Comment: Результат выводит в таком виде Array
(
    [id] => 210
    [0] => 210
    [username] => XXX666777
    [1] => XXX666777
    [pole1] => 2016-03-12
    [2] => 2016-03-12
    [pole2] => 0000-00-00
    [3] => 0000-00-00
)     А как вывести данные только из поля username?

Comment: Да, это дамп массива, вам в каком виде требуется результат?

Comment: В простом виде. Чтобы человек смог посмотреть значение.

Comment: echo $data['username']  выводит просто значение поля

Comment: Т.е. это значение увидит тот человек у которого $_SESSION['USERNAME']  совпадает. Если нет совпадения то он ничего не увидит.

Comment: Да, следует взять значение $cat->fetch() и воспользоваться им как обычным массивом.

Comment: Вставил это $cat->fetch($data['username']) но все равно выводится как массив

Comment: Нет, нужно, примерно так (поправил в ответе, тут не удобно код размещать)
$result = $cat->fetch();
echo $result['username'];

Comment: Спасибо огромное.  Заработало!

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы в базе он искал в поле username у которого рядом есть поле дата и чтобы искал совпадение только в последней строчке по дате. А остальные игнорировал

Comment: Для этого можно отсортировать результаты по полю даты при помощи конструкции ORDER BY pole1 DESC и ограничить выборку последней записью при помощи конструкции LIMIT 1. Впрочем одиночный вызов fetch() и так вернет только одну запись.

Comment: "SELECT * 
              FROM table1
              WHERE SUBSTR(USERNAME, -6) = :username  ORDER BY pole1 DESC LIMIT 1";   Правильный запрос?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, да, все должно быть верно, но лучше проверить, соответствует ли он ожиданию.

Comment: Все равно показывает запись. Нужно именно чтобы сначала по дате  т.е. брал последнею запись по дате и искал только в ней совпадение, если есть совпадение то вывод информации. Сейчас он по всей базе ищет.

Comment: Или лучше сделать отдельную таблицу и в ней держать только последнею запись  и уже только в ней искать, а на следующий день переместить запись и добавить в нее новую?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL умеет искать последние символы примерно так `s LIKE '%abcdef'`. Наша задача подготовить маску поиска из 6 последний символов имени. В примере подразумеваю использование UTF-8 (я в курсе про цифры, но сюрпризы не люблю):

```
$lastChars = mb_substr($_SESSION['USERNAME'], -6);
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE username LIKE ?");
$sth->execute(['%'.$lastChars]);
while ($row = $sth->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  var_dump($row);
}
```